# PHP Select Unique Values from Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

Using PHP and MySQL I have generated an array (from an API lookup). A `var_dump` of the array can her seen [here](https://pastebin.com/kNqpdazK).

I would like to return **only** unique 'title' values from this array.

My code so far is;

```
foreach($response["Items"]["Item"] as $item)
{
    $title = $item["ItemAttributes"]["Title"];
}
```

A `var_dump` of `$title` produces;

```
string(5) "Panic" string(5) "Panic" string(73) "Captain Flinn and the Pirate Dinosaurs: Missing Treasure! (Captain Flinn)"
```

You can see that there are two string values named "Panic".

I have tried `array_unique` but can't seem to get it working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why are you not try distinct() function of mysql when you getting record using query

Comment: @mickmackusa tags updated

Answer (score 0):

Try with this trick: if title is already present it will not added.

```
$titlesFounded = [];

foreach($response["Items"]["Item"] as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item["ItemAttributes"]["Title"], $titlesFounded)) {
        $titlesFounded[] = $item["ItemAttributes"]["Title"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `[]` from `$titlesFounded[]` in `if`

Comment: There was a typo. Fixed.